# Vivado timing setup problem

Tags: clock, vivado

I have a pipelined datapath I made in class that I would like to put into another project to make an SOC.

In the original Vivado project I created it in, the datapath can be implemented with a clock period of 5 ns. However, when I add the module and all of its dependencies into a new project, the required clock period jumps up to 14 ns. I can't figure out why this is happening. Any recommendations as to where to look would be much appreciated.

Note: I am running Vivado 2020.2

**UPDATE**

There is a setup timing violation between two registers that shouldn't even be related to each other.

[image]

[image]
[image]

The ALUInput2[31:0] dotted line runs from the output of the IDEXRegister back around to the input of the Execute Unit since the Execute Unit actually falls after the IDEXRegister.

These registers don't interact in my design. The WriteBackAddress is computed in parallel with the ALUResult. But coming out of the EXMEMRegister the ALUResult is already calculated and is just used to address into BRAM. The WriteBackAddress is actually a register address and not even a memory address.

It really makes no sense why Vivado is drawing these long paths.

Comment: I'd kindly recommend this document for an introduction on how to proceed: https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/2018.1-English/ug945-vivado-using-constraints-tutorial

Comment: Which portion? The constraint file is the same in both projects. I haven't added in any other part of the system yet.

Comment: Putting a register at both the input and output ports of the design should isolate it timing wise from anything else its connected to.  That might solve your problem (at the expense of 1 clock cycle of latency).